# Hello world in NASM with LINK.EXE and WinAPI

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm

I'm trying to get a simple Hello world program in NASM to run.
I want to print to the console without using C-Libraries, interfacing directly with WinAPI.

I am using the Visual Studio provided LINK.EXE for linking.

Here's my code so far:

```c
section .data
    message:     db 'Hello world!',10    ; 'Hello world!' plus a linefeed character
    messageLen:  db $-message        ; Length of the 'Hello world!' string

    global _start
    extern  GetStdHandle
    extern  WriteConsoleW
    extern  ExitProcess

section .text

_start:
    ; DWORD  bytes;    
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, byte 8

    ; hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    mov     ecx, -11
    call    GetStdHandle

    ; WriteFile(hstdOut, message, length(message), &bytes, 0);
    mov     rcx, rax
    mov     rdx, message
    mov     r8,  messageLen
    lea     r9,  [rsp-4]
    push    0
    call    WriteConsoleW

    ; ExitProcess(0)
    mov     rcx, 0
    call    ExitProcess

    ret
```

Which I assemble and link like this:

```
nasm -f win64 .\ASM.ASM
link /entry:_start /nodefaultlib /subsystem:console .\ASM.obj "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64\kernel32.lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64\user32.lib"
```

However when I run the resulting .exe file, I get nothing.

Some things I tried so far are

- Using the decorated names (like _GetStdHandle@4), which resulted in the linker complaining about unresolved references
- Not trying to print anything and calling Sleep, which resulted in the process sleeping indefinitely
- Exiting with a different return code, which once again did nothing

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Fixed calling convention

Comment: your code is *x64*, not *x86*. and you need first learn *x64* calling conventions

Comment: I've fixed the calling convention problem, but the end result is still the same. See the edit to the question

Comment: You still haven't fully fixed the calling convention: you don't reserve 32 bytes of shadow space so the functions you call could step on your stack space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three problems with your revised code. The first is:

```
message:     db 'Hello world!',10    ; 'Hello world!' plus a linefeed character
messageLen:  db $-message            ; Length of the 'Hello world!' string
```

You defined `messageLen` to be a byte containing the length of the message and storing that value at the address of `messageLen`. You then do this:

```
mov     r8,  messageLen
```

That would move the address of label `messageLen` to r8. What you really should have done is define `messageLen` as an assembly time constant like this:

```
messageLen equ $-message             ; Length of the 'Hello world!' string
```

The second problem is that you define the the string as a sequence of single byte characters:

```
message:     db 'Hello world!',10    ; 'Hello world!' plus a linefeed character
```

There is nothing wrong with this, but to print them out you need to use the Ansi version of the function `WriteConsole` which is `WriteConsoleA`. Using `WriteConsoleW` printed the string as Unicode (UTF-16 on Windows 2000 and later, UTS-2 on NT4 and earlier versions of Windows).

---

The third problem is with regards to a mandatory 32 bytes of shadow space before the stack based parameter(s) are placed on the stack before making a function call. You also need to make sure the stack (RSP) is a 16-byte aligned value at the point of making a function call. These requirement can be found in the [Microsoft 64-bit calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019).

Code that would take this into account would look like this:

```
section .data
    message:     db 'Hello world!',10    ; 'Hello world!' plus a linefeed character
    messageLen equ $-message      ; Length of the 'Hello world!' string

    global _start
    extern  GetStdHandle
    extern  WriteConsoleA
    extern  ExitProcess

section .text

_start:
    ; At _start the stack is 8 bytes misaligned because there is a return
    ; address to the MSVCRT runtime library on the stack.
    ; 8 bytes of temporary storage for `bytes`.
    ; allocate 32 bytes of stack for shadow space.
    ; 8 bytes for the 5th parameter of WriteConsole.
    ; An additional 8 bytes for padding to make RSP 16 byte aligned.
    sub     rsp, 8+8+8+32
    ; At this point RSP is aligned on a 16 byte boundary and all necessary
    ; space has been allocated.

    ; hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    mov     ecx, -11
    call    GetStdHandle

    ; WriteFile(hstdOut, message, length(message), &bytes, 0);
    mov     rcx, rax
    mov     rdx, message
    mov     r8,  messageLen
    lea     r9,  [rsp-16]         ; Address for `bytes`
    ; RSP-17 through RSP-48 are the 32 bytes of shadow space
    mov     qword [rsp-56], 0     ; First stack parameter of WriteConsoleA function
    call    WriteConsoleA

    ; ExitProcess(0)
    ;    mov     rcx, 0
    ;    call    ExitProcess

    ; alternatively you can exit by setting RAX to 0
    ; and doing a ret

    add rsp, 8+8+32+8             ; Restore the stack pointer.
    xor eax, eax                  ; RAX = return value = 0
    ret
```

Comment: 3rd problem: didn't reserve shadow space.  BTW, when you say "unicode", does that mean UTF-16 in this case?  Because message is valid UTF-8 unicode.

Comment: @PeterCordes : There is also the issue of stack alignment (and not just shadow space). As for Unicode it is UCS-2 on NT 4 and earlier Windows OSes, UTF-16 on Windows 2000 and later.

Comment: NASM has a `__utf16__` command for defining UTF-16 strings, so encoding isn't a problem.

Comment: I realize this is kind of old, but I think your stack offsets are wrong. Negative offsets relative to `rsp` don't look correct. I believe the `lea r9, [rsp-16]` should be `lea r9, [rsp+40]` and the `mov qword [rsp-56], 0` should be `mov qword [rsp+32], 0`. The shadow space is `rsp` to `rsp+31` inclusive.

Comment: @Jester : I'll fix it. I think what happened was I originally did a version of this program that used the OP's idea of copying RSP to RBP and I had the code relative to RBP. I figure  I removed RBP, started using RSP and never fixed the offsets.